# How to show the hidden field in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

Fetching some variables in hidden field using struts2

```
<s:hidden name="ABCFormBean.dependentLists[0].lastNameEng" id="h_dependantLastNameEng_id"/>
```

I need to display the same in the same page

```
<s:property value="ABCFormBean.dependentLists[0].lastNameEng"/>
```

doesnt work

how to display the content?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"; if it's showing up in the hidden field, it should show up using the property tag.

Comment: nothing gets displayed using <s:property value="ABCFormBean.depLists[0].firstNameEng"/>

Comment: 1) dependentLists vs depLists ? 2) lastNameEng vs firstNameEng ? 3) ABCFormBean should be aBCFormBean ?

Comment: sorry.. still not working.. just updated the code

Comment: Again, if it's showing up in the form field, it'll show up in the property tag, assuming the correct OGNL expression. If it isn't, we'd need more details.

Comment: Post your action class with beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing gets displayed because the property value doesn't map the value in the value stack. Bu default the action is on top of the value stack. If you map properties they should should be initialized and have getters and setters. To display

```
<s:property value="ABCFormBean.depLists[0].firstNameEng"/>
```

the following method calls are expected

```
getABCFormBean().getDepLists().get(0).getFirstNameEng()
```

If you can get this value in the action method, then you would have the values been displayed by the property tag.

Comment: I know it was a ridiculous question as It was my first day with Struts and had a deadline to finish the work. Thanks a lot for being patient and explaining the concept.